# Quelle est la différence entre « broyer », « concasser » et « moudre » ?

Tags: sens

Ces trois mots semblent tous vouloir dire exactement la même chose : réduire en morceaux, en miettes.

La différence, s'il y en a, serait-elle en rapport avec la taille des morceaux ?

Answer (score 2):

L'emploi des mots « broyer », « concasser » et « moudre » ne tient pas à la taille des morceaux obtenus par l'un ou l'autre processus, mais par la façon dont ce processus est exécuté.

« Broyer » se fait par pression ou par choc, on peut broyer avec ses dents, entre ses doigts, avec ses pieds, etc... éventuellement sous les roues d'un camion, mais sans instrument particulier. Un synonyme usuel de « broyer » est « écraser ».

« Concasser » se fait en principe avec un instrument, en cuisine on peut concasser des fruits secs ou des graines (noix, noisettes, poivre, café...) à l'aide d'un pilon. On peut concasser des pierres avec un marteau, dans les travaux publics on utilise des concasseurs.

« Moudre » peut donner parfois le même résultat que broyer ou concasser pour un même matériau mais l'opération est effectuée avec un moulin (poivre, café, sel,...) ou une meule (farine, céréales en général), la taille des morceaux dépendant du type de lame ou de meule.

Comment: Évidemment le mot dépend du processus, mais je crois que la façon dont on classifie les processus dépend bien du résultat désiré. *Concasser* résulte en des morceaux de taille irrégulière. *Moudre* résulte en une poudre. *Broyer* est plus vague. *Écraser* donne un résultat aplati.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Selon le matériau (ça dépend de la dureté et du taux d'humidité) je peux obtenir une poudre en broyant ou concassant, avec plus d'huile de coude qu'avec un moulin. Et un moulin ne donne pas forcément une poudre, tout dépend de son réglage et de la façon de l'utiliser.

Answer (score 0):

Je suis entièrement d'accord avec la réponse de @None, j'ajouterais des définitions dictionnaires comme références ; ces définitions proviennent de larousse.fr, ainsi que les définitions de quelques autres mots similaires:

> **Broyer** : Réduire quelque chose en parcelles extrêmement ténues en le soumettant à un choc ou à une pression : Broyer des grains.

> **Concasser** : Réduire en menus fragments des matières dures ou sèches.

> **Meuler** : Réduire une substance en poudre par le moyen d'un moulin ou d'une meule : Moudre du blé, du café.

> **Écraser** : Faire subir à quelque chose une pression ou des chocs tels qu'il en est broyé, brisé : *Écraser de l'ail avec un pilon.*

> **Pulvériser** : Réduire une matière en poudre : *Pulvériser de la craie ; du charbon.*

---

**Meuler** et **pulvériser** brisent donc dans une poudre où **meuler** est fait avec un.e moulin/meule, **broyer** et **écraser** impliquent un choc ou une pression, et **concasser** est seulment fait sur des matières dures et sèches.